# Bluetooth service failed to set mode

Tags: bluetooth, 21.04

So, I tried to use my wireless headpods but found that Ubuntu 21.04 has a bug:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-05-26 07:40:51 MSK; 53min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 822 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8566)
     Memory: 1.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─822 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 26 07:40:47 UbuntuLinux bluetoothd[822]: Bluetooth daemon 5.56
May 26 07:40:47 UbuntuLinux systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
May 26 07:40:51 UbuntuLinux bluetoothd[822]: Starting SDP server
May 26 07:40:51 UbuntuLinux systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
May 26 07:40:53 UbuntuLinux bluetoothd[822]: Bluetooth management interface 1.19 initialized
May 26 07:40:53 UbuntuLinux bluetoothd[822]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
May 26 07:41:24 UbuntuLinux bluetoothd[822]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
May 26 07:41:31 UbuntuLinux bluetoothd[822]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
May 26 07:41:31 UbuntuLinux bluetoothd[822]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.80 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It worked for me

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
sudo systemctl stop bluetooth
sudo systemctl status bluetooth
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Comment: You stopped the blurtooth service, then asked its status.  Why?  I would have expected the last step to be a `start`

Comment: Above did not work for me, but this did: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/602739/115743

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

The [mentioned answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/602739/209677) with `hciconfig` from [bluez package](http://www.bluez.org/) worked on an Ubuntu 22.04. With root privileges:

```sh
hciconfig hci0 down  # Close HCI device.
rmmod btusb          # Remove btusb module from the kernel
modprobe btusb       # Add it back
hciconfig hci0 up    # Open and initialize HCI device
```

On one line

```
hciconfig hci0 down && rmmod btusb && modprobe btusb && hciconfig hci0 up
```

If still doesn't work, check unplugging/plugging again, check if listed (`sudo hciconfig -a`) and if it's not blocked (`sudo rfkill list`).

If using a Sony WH-1000XM4, hold power button until pairing mode is enabled, around 6 seconds.

Comment: This works until reboot. And then I have to do this again. Not sure why the device doesn’t come back up after reboot. And journalctl says “failed to set mode”