# Bluetooth devices not showing up in pairing mode Ubuntu 21.10 / Kernel 5.15

Tags: bluetooth, connection, 21.10

**Found a Solution here:** [Bluetooth service failed to set mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340713/bluetooth-service-failed-to-set-mode)

My Bluetooth seems to be running but it will not show the devices in pairing mode.
I have attached the status below. Thank you.

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-01-31 02:48:45 PST; 8h ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 921 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18893)
     Memory: 1.9M
        CPU: 303ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─921 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 31 02:48:45 NeoNeb-Ubuntu bluetoothd[921]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
Jan 31 02:48:56 NeoNeb-Ubuntu bluetoothd[921]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jan 31 02:48:56 NeoNeb-Ubuntu bluetoothd[921]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Jan 31 02:48:56 NeoNeb-Ubuntu bluetoothd[921]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Jan 31 02:48:56 NeoNeb-Ubuntu bluetoothd[921]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Jan 31 02:48:56 NeoNeb-Ubuntu bluetoothd[921]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Jan 31 02:48:56 NeoNeb-Ubuntu bluetoothd[921]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Jan 31 02:48:56 NeoNeb-Ubuntu bluetoothd[921]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Jan 31 02:48:56 NeoNeb-Ubuntu bluetoothd[921]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
Jan 31 10:58:26 NeoNeb-Ubuntu bluetoothd[921]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
```

Comment: Where did kernel 5.15 come from? What happens if you use the proper standard kernel for 21.10?

Comment: I had a problem with my motherboard where the wifi didn't work. (msi pro z690-a) I had the same problem with windows until I updated the drivers. I read on here that the newer kernel would support my mobo out of the box and it did. I was on the standard kernel before I switched with no network connections working. switching to 5.15 got the wifi working right away and then the bluetooth followed with some tweaking. I also had to issues with the nvidia graphics card not working right with the new kernel but I just had to switch the nvidia x to a newer version as well.

Comment: You may also have a BIOS problem. `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: Bios 1.00, it does say there is some sort of bios bug on startup screen. Its not affecting my usage though at this point. Should I be worried?

Comment: Tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard, and I'll take a look.

Comment: (intel) MSI Pro Z690-A WIFI DDR4
Thanks man, really appreciate you helping me out with this

Comment: Thank you for the info

Comment: You're more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bluetooth**

Jan 31 10:58:26 NeoNeb-Ubuntu bluetoothd[921]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)

Source: [Bluetooth service failed to set mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340713/bluetooth-service-failed-to-set-mode)

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
sudo systemctl stop bluetooth
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
sudo systemctl status bluetooth
```

**BIOS**

MSI Pro Z690-A WIFI DDR4

You have BIOS 1.00 dated 9/15/2021. There's a newer BIOS available, version 1.26 (beta) dated 1/25/2022. There's a slightly older version 1.1 dated 12/13/2021. I'd recommend version 1.1. Either can be downloaded [here](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/PRO-Z690-A-WIFI-DDR4/support#down-bios).

How to update the BIOS is [PDF](https://storage-asset.msi.com/files/pdf/How_to_flash_the_BIOS.pdf) or [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRyFMf0D9Lc).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS